# how to format var_dump output ($key and $value)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

PHP CODE/index.php

```
<?php        
  var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

HTML CODE

```
<html> 
<body> 
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /> 
Age: <input type="text" name="age" /> 
Addess: <input type="text" name="ads" /> 
<input type="submit" /> </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

OUTPUT

```
array(3) { ["fname"]=> string(5) "USER_INPUT_NAME" ["age"]=> string(6) "USER_INPUT_AGE" ["ads"]=> string(5) "USER_INPUT_ADDRESS" }
```

So what i want to do is how to format that output as a normal array using foreach ?

Comment: See [`var_export`](http://us.php.net/var_export).

Comment: So what do you want to know? How to format a var_dump or how to iterate and display an array?

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need all the info provided by `var_dump` you can use HTML `<pre>` tag with `print_r`:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($query); echo '</pre>';
echo "<br>================================</br>";
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($query); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
   if($key != 'submit') {
      echo $key . "=>" . $val . "<br/>";
   }
}
```

Comment: array(3) { ["fname"]=> string(7) "Hasanka" ["age"]=> string(2) "27" ["ads"]=> string(7) "Urapola" } fname=>Hasanka
age=>27
ads=>Urapola

Comment: it works but var_dump result and other result is still print outed

Comment: @user2036613 That would be your fault, for not commenting out that particular line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on server on which you can install PHP extensions, try [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org). I used it for years before knowing it, because it's part of the installation of [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com).

Answer (score -1):

go on, format  that output as a normal array using [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)

Comment: but if i use a variable to contain output array.it's not working...how ever var_dump(_POST); print values as a array